# Generating Dependency Report Using Play Dependency Management

Tags: playframework, ivy

Play's dependency management uses ivy under the hood. Is there a way the play can be asked to generate a dependency report? This is typically done in ivy through [ivy:report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/report.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$play dependencies
```

Display the dependencies summary. [Play 2.0.1]